# How do I remove duplicate data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to display lines that are not repeated, but only with their neighbors, they should remain in the entire database (also in a single copy) in sqlite. Here's what I'm missing:
**Initial database:**

```
(id (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)|security_id|date_and_time|price)
(1|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:51|100.2)
(2|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:51|100.2)
(3|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:51|100.2)
(4|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:52|100.2)
(5|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:52|100.3)
(6|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:52|100.2)
...
```

**What should be output:**

```
(4|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:51|100.2)
(5|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:52|100.3)
(6|AAPL|2020-08-21 09:59:52|100.2)
...
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you conduct a thorough [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make any attempt?

Comment: I think you should describe clearly for what columns are you looking for to be different as rows proceed, and in which order. In this case we're trying to solve a puzzle :)

Comment: You should define what you exactly mean by *lines that are not repeated, but only with their neighbors*. The existing answers define them differently :-) What should be returned for e.g.`1,2,1,1,2,1,1`, the 1st row of a repeated group or the last row? And for or `1,1,1,1`, i.e. all rows share the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lag and Case:

```
SELECT X.ID, X.SECURITY_ID, X.DATE_AND_TIME, X.PRICE FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN NEXT_VALUE = 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN NEXT_VALUE = PRICE THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END AS CHECK_VALUE, A.* FROM (
SELECT A.*,LEAD(A.PRICE, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY ID) NEXT_VALUE FROM 
TAB A ) A ) X WHERE CHECK_VALUE = 1 ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Yes, it will support if `ISNULL` is replaced by `COALESCE` . +1 ( You can check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9cb6fc9fdf50cacc6bbf84bfb8388357) out )

Comment: Thanks@BarbarosÖzhan. Edited it based on your comments.

Comment: No need for `coalesce`, LAG/LEAD support a default value replace the NULL in the first row: `LEAD(A.PRICE,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY ID)`

Comment: It does not work in this case:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=74fe66f16b492a1de62a1eca463901d4

Comment: Ah yes, right as we already used @dnoeth , then I just focused on the function `ISNULL`

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks,good point.Lag and Lead have a third parameter to define the default value.

Comment: @mohdatif The row with id = 7 should not be in the results because the row with id = 6 is exactly the same.

Comment: @forpas You have an additional test case and as per user requirement row id 6 should not be in the result set while 7th will be.

Comment: If it was so the the row with id = 3 should also be in the results.

Comment: @forpas, no logic is that last value of repeated set should be included so first 3 are not inlcuded and then last of that set is included and hence 6th wont be included and 7th will be.

Comment: @dnoeth Updated the answer with LAG default value of 0.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a genius and just a good person!)

Comment: @johnMitrich what happens in this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=74fe66f16b492a1de62a1eca463901d4 Do you want the row with id = 7 in the results?

Comment: This query is overly complex and can be simplified to: `SELECT X.ID, X.SECURITY_ID, X.DATE_AND_TIME, X.PRICE 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT A.*, LEAD(A.PRICE) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NEXT_VALUE 
   FROM TAB A
 ) AS X 
WHERE NEXT_VALUE <> PRICE
   OR NEXT_VALUE IS NULL
ORDER BY ID;`

Answer (score 0):

is your source data containing duplicates? If so, the easiest way to strip them out in SQL is to firstly import them into a 'staging' table to help strip out the dups.

Like a normal table, a staging table acts as a 'stage' to carry out specific coding instructions before being inserted into the final table.

For example, if you want to create table1 and ensure there is no dups in there you can first create table STG_Table1.

Import your records into STG_Table1 - there's no need to add constraints or be particular over datatypes.

Once STG_Table1 is populated, you can create a stored procedure containing a "Row_Number() over (Partition by 'column name'* order by 'column name') " to ID your specific rows, and only return the '1' that you're after!

*Usually the column that's being duplicated

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! These are not exactly duplicates, in general, all records are unique (It's just that the time is not indicated in milliseconds), but you need to remove those lines that have the same price with the neighbor on top!

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT *,
  LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_id,
  LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) next_id
FROM tablename
```

returns the *neighboring* `id`s of all `id`s of the table.
So you can do a `LEFT` join of the table to that query and filter out all the matching rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) prev_id,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) next_id
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t LEFT JOIN cte c
ON t.id IN (c.prev_id, c.next_id)
AND t.security_id = c.security_id AND t.date_and_time = c.date_and_time AND t.price = c.price
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7d83d16ff3a380df1d9abd655e56cb23).
Results:

```
> id | security_id | date_and_time       | price
> -: | :---------- | :------------------ | ----:
>  4 | AAPL        | 2020-08-21 09:59:52 | 100.2
>  5 | AAPL        | 2020-08-21 09:59:52 | 100.3
>  6 | AAPL        | 2020-08-21 09:59:52 | 100.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to find rows with any column of the next row is different than the previous one, except for the identity (`id` e.g. primary key ) column. You can use `LAG()` function  In order to figure out the comparison between the current and the previous values for the columns among each individual rows when ordered by id values :

```
SELECT id, security_id, date_and_time, price
  FROM
  (
   SELECT t.*,
          LAG(security_id,1,security_id) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS lg_security_id,
          LAG(date_and_time,1,date_and_time) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS lg_date_and_time,
          LAG(price,1,price) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS lg_price
     FROM tab t
  ) t1
 WHERE NOT
    (      lg_price         = price 
       AND lg_date_and_time = date_and_time
       AND lg_security_id   = lg_security_id 
    )
 ORDER BY id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=977fec91c89aadf5902911ca3ed3c897)</kbd>